# unable to run Android Studio in Intellij : java.lang.AssertionError: Bazel paths exist only in AndroidStudio development mode

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, sdk

I want to run 2 applications, 1 on my PC using javaFX and another on my Android phone, to transfer objects via a USB connection. I can run a basic app template from the standalone Android Studio program just fine, but when I try to do the same using the Android Studio plugin inside Intellij, I get this error:

```
Can't download Android Plugin component: android-plugin-resources: Check logs for details
```

I have tried deleting and reinstalling Android SDK, tried different SDK versions, download Android Studio SDK FZvia Commandline tools, followed various turtorials for setting up Android Studio inside Intellij but to no avail.

Is there another approach if I can't get this to work? Is it possible to run the standalone Android Studio and Intellij in the same module/solution, and call functions between each project?

build.gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "32.0.0"

    defaultConfig { 
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Log details:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Bazel paths exist only in AndroidStudio development mode
> at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths.findEmbeddedInstaller(EmbeddedDistributionPaths.java:133)
> at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidLaunchTasksProvider.lambda$getDeployTasks$0(AndroidLaunchTasksProvider.java:184)
> at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask.getLocalInstaller(AbstractDeployTask.java:147)
> at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask.run(AbstractDeployTask.java:103)
> at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:190)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:962)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:472)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:235)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:235)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Comment: See this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-287064#focus=Comments-27-5712884.0-0

Comment: What version of IntelliJ IDEA is in use?

Comment: 2020.3.2(Ultimate Edition). yea i did notice that the program tried to download a plugin, but the link doesnt work. I will update my IntelliJ if this doesn't work.

Comment: thx, the solution from the link worked!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Just update Intellij to the newest version, turns out the problem was that Intellij  was attempting to download a plugin every time my program is run, but the link it's trying to access no longer works. By updating the installed intellij version 2020.3.2 to the newest version , the issue is fixed.